# How to get function return array single line ? Below my code

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-hmvc

Class:

```
 class profile_setting extends MY_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
    public function index()
    {
        echo $this->table()->breadcrump;
    }
    public function table(){
        return array('table'=>'tbl_users','breadcrump'=>'Profile Settings','redirect_url'=>'dashboard');
    }
}
```

Above code i got error when i use this single line like below

echo $this->table()->breadcrump;
 or
echo $this->table()['breadcrump'];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with -

```
$breadcrumb = $this->table();
echo $breadcrumb['breadcrump'];
```

for single line try with -

```
echo $this->table()['breadcrump'];
```

Comment: i need single line how to i do ?

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work for you in single line.

```
 public function index()
 {
   echo $this->table()['breadcrump'];
 }
```

**[Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/oUUDlz)**

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way I found to do bread crumbs on codeigniter is. You can use this with bootstrap is well.

```
public function index()

    $data['breadcrumbs'] = array();

    $data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
        'text' => 'Home',
        'href' => site_url('admin/common/dashboard')
    );

    $data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
        'text' => 'Banners',
        'href' => site_url('admin/design/banners')
    );

  $this->load->view('folder/file', $data); 
}
```

On view

```
<ul class="breadcrumb">
    <?php foreach ($breadcrumbs as $breadcrumb) { ?>
    <li><a href="<?php echo $breadcrumb['href']; ?>"><?php echo $breadcrumb['text']; ?></a></li>
    <?php } ?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sadikhasan and sgt have given you the answer as you are accessing an array you have to use that way.

if the return was a object then you have to use this way
$this->table()->breadcrump

But for this you are accessing an returned array so @Sadikhasan 's answer is your  answer.